# Enable windows azure authentication returns null name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, azure

I have downloaded the fall update of VS2012, I have a windows Azure active directory account and an Office 365 account

If I create a standard MVC 4.5 internet project, remove [InitializeSimpleMembership] from the Account controller and enable Windows Azure Authentication I go through the registration process but when I run the solution I get an error on the login page because user.identity.name is null.

Can any tell me how to create an initial MVC project and enable Windows Azure Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> click on Extensions and Updates -> Click on Online in the left pane -> Search for Identity and Access Tool and install it. OR go to this link http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e?SRC=VSIDE.

After you install the extension, you'll see a link called "Identity and Access..." when you right click on your MVC project in VS. Click on it and it will walk you through setting up your project.

Comment: Thanks - I have looked into this with the information you gave. Seems that Windows Live does not return the user name anyway also you have to get the Realm from your Azure account (Active directory / Manage /Relying party applications) - but once you have that you can use the Identity and Access link in VS2012.